# LibGDX - Is there a maximum number of keys that can be pressed at the same time?

Tags: java, input, libgdx

So I've tried using `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed` (and previously an `InputProcessor`) to get input and move the 2d player on the screen like this:

```
private void handleInput(float delta) {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
        moveTo(new Vector2(0, -speed * delta));

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) 
        moveTo(new Vector2(0, speed * delta));

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
        moveTo(new Vector2(-speed * delta, 0));

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
        moveTo(new Vector2(speed * delta, 0));

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE))
        attack();
}
```

Movement works as intended, diagonally as well. But for some reason whenever the player moves **up and left**, **down and left** or **down and right** the `attack` function at the end can't be called for some reason. Does this have to do with a limited number of keys that can be pressed and processed at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

My keyboard was the problem ([ghosting](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/keyboardghostingdemo.mspx)), not libGDX.